# How do I convert an user input only if its a certain variable?

Tags: python, variables

okay so I have the code shown below, where I ask the user for the temperature. they obviously have to anwser in numbers, but I want to put in a joke response for if they don't. how can I convert a variable only if it's of a certain type?

```
base_temp = input("What is the temperature outside?:" )
if base_temp == str:
    print("ok that is not a real temperature.")
    print("you stupid liar i HATE you.")
else: temp = int(base_temp)

if temp >= 0 and temp <= 30 :
    print("that's nice. Go outside. NOW!")
if temp >= 31 or temp < -10 :
    print("okay you can stay inside.")
    print("you still need to go outside though, stinky.")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the built in `isdigit()` function which returns true if the given string consists of only digits, so for an ex:

```
if base_temp.isdigit():
    print("valid temp")
else:
    print("invalid temp")
```

Comment: In this case, `isdigit()` cannot deal with negative tempatures. '-1'.isdigit() is False.

Answer (score 0):

Use exception handling to do this. modified the code a bit, hope it helps.

it can also handle negative numbers.

```
base_temp = input("What is the temperature outside?:" )

try:
    temp = int(base_temp)
    if temp >= 0 and temp <= 30 :
        print("that's nice. Go outside. NOW!")
    if temp >= 31 or temp < -10 :
        print("okay you can stay inside.")
        print("you still need to go outside though, stinky.")
        
except ValueError:
    print("ok that is not a real temperature.")
    print("you stupid liar i HATE you.")
```

Comment: check [Handling Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) for more information.